# How to get top 3 Positions (Values) from array in PHP Including Duplicate

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a sorted array in descending order such as with values `100 , 98, 96, 90 ...`.
and I am using `foreach()` loop to iterate over the array and use `if condition` with limit `3` such as `

```
foreach($array as $arr){
if(loop_counter<3)
{ 
 echo 'something'; 
}}
```

to get top `3` positions. but the problem is that if there exist two same values such as `100 , 98, 98, 96, 90 . .` then limits should increase from `3` to `4` so that on position `2` there exist two values `98, 98` and position `3` contain value `90` instead of `2nd` `98` remember that I need both duplicate number on one position such as two students with same marks stands against one position.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the solution for this:

```
$array = [100, 98, 96, 96, 95];
$count = 0;
$length = count($array);
foreach($array as $key => $arr){
  if($count<3)
  { 
     echo $arr . ", ";
     if(($length != $key + 1) && $array[$key] != $array[$key + 1]) 
     {
        $count++;         
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: it is not necessary that duplicate number are consecutive

Comment: @mahesh in question you tell that you sort array in desc order. Then values are consecutive.

Comment: Before loop you just need to sort array in desc order before loop statement.

Comment: @AnkurMishra array is sorted before loop in descending order.

Comment: It is working fine. Open link and click on execute code to check output: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d7f2f2425b5cdbe9a3d1204dfb41f023903cbaff

Comment: i think it's better to use array_unique before the iteration@AnkurMishra

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this

```
   $len=3;
    $selectedArray=[]
    $i = 0;

    while($i <= $len) {
 array_push($selectedArray, $array[$i]);

    if(in_array($array[$i], $array))
    {$len++;
    }

        $i++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is what are you looking for, but you can use below code as example

```php
    $a = [100, 100, 98, 97, 97, 97, 96];
   
    foreach(array_slice(array_count_values($a), 0, 3, true) as $number => $repeat) {
        var_dump(array_fill(0, $repeat, $number)); 
    }
```

Result

```php
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  int(100)
  [1]=>
  int(100)
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  int(98)
}
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  int(97)
  [1]=>
  int(97)
  [2]=>
  int(97)
}
```

[Live Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0833d60c5107532bcb2b17049bd159afd75145aa)

Answer (score 0):

Also this, will work well

```
<?php

$array = array(100,98,98,98,96,96,90);
$arr_counter = 0;
$items = array();
foreach($array as $arr){


   $items[] = $arr; //capture all values in this cycle

   #get all values that are repeating then add it to a new array
   $nrr = array_unique(array_diff_assoc($items, array_unique($items)));

    #If the number is repeating again dont add to our counter $arr_counter
   if (!in_array($arr, $nrr)) {  $arr_counter = $arr_counter+1; }  

   echo $arr;  echo ' | position '; echo $arr_counter; echo '<br>';

   if  ($arr_counter == 3) { die(); }
} 


?>
```

Result: [php sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/38dc2fb89f55a28b02dbd37fbd0f5e22280d13a2)

```
100 | position 1
98 | position 2
98 | position 2
98 | position 2
96 | position 3
```